# How to stop action from proceeding in YII button?

Tags: ajax, yii

If I have a button:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'label'=>'Go',
    'buttonType'=>'ajaxButton', 
    'type'=>'primary', 
    'url'=>$this->createUrl('Something/Doit'),
    'htmlOptions' => array(
      'style' => 'width: 100%;'
    ),
    'ajaxOptions'=>array(
      'type' => 'POST',
      'beforeSend' => '
        function( request ) {
          if (wasSuccess) {
                   // proceed
              }
          else {
                  // execution
              }

        }'
      ,
      'success' => '
        function( data ) {
           // do stuff
        }'

    ),
  ));
```

How can I edit the "wasSuccess" part so that if wasSuccess is false, that it stops the execution and does not actually do the action associated with this button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `return false` from the `beforeSend` callback the request will be cancelled, so:

```
'beforeSend' => '
    function( request ) {
        if (!wasSuccess) return false;
    }'
```

Comment: Tried that. Didnt work. Tried it again. It works. Thanks! I must've typed something wrong the first time!